# Docker high disk utilization with VFS storage driver

Tags: docker, filesystems, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Docker with the vfs storage driver which is significantly taking up disk space on my system (the backing filesystem is `overlayfs` which, unfortunately, is preventing me from using `overlay2` with Docker). To prevent disk overuse, I tried configuring a quota using the following `daemon.json` config (as detailed [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-vfs-storage-driver)):

```json
{
  "storage-driver": "vfs",
  "storage-opts": ["size=256M"]
}
```

When trying to start docker with this config, I get the following error and the service fails to start:

```
Jul 22 15:17:29 my-device dockerd[47350]: failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: Filesystem does not support, or has not enabled quotas: vfs
```

How do I go about either

1. Enforcing a disk use quota on docker **OR**
2. Configure Docker to not use ridiculous amounts of disk space?

I have tried using other storage drivers but I didn't find one which works (off the shelf) with an overlayfs backed filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up configuring Docker to use the overlay2 storage driver by having Docker use an LVM mount on my Ubuntu system for storage. Here are some of the steps after creating a volume group:

1. Create an LVM partition for Docker `sudo lvcreate -n docker -L 10G lvm`
2. Format the logical volume with ext4 filesystem `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/lvm/docker`
3. Mount the Docker directory `sudo mount /dev/lvm/docker /var/lib/docker`
4. Update storage driver to `overlay2` and restart Docker.

Note: To have the mount persist across record, add a corresponding mount instruction to `/etc/fstab`